# Word(s) exclusion in pattern without using -v option in (e)grep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Is it possible to exclude exact word(s) in (e)grep using a pattern only without using -v option. For example, since `()` groups a pattern or an exact string (), I thought `egrep [^(main)]` will match substrings without the exact word `main` but what happens is it excludes the letter `m,a,i,n`. I'm still learning regular expression in bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: There's several things you might mean by that. [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative look ahead regex for rejecting a line that contains `main` as whole word and don't have to use `-v` necessarily.

```
grep -P '^(?!.*\bmain\b).*$' bash.txt
```

Here, `-P` enables `Perl regular expression`

Before are the contents of a file named bash.txt,

```
hello 123
hello world
hello main world
some main text
some mainly text
```

And upon running above command it prints this output,

```
hello 123
hello world
some mainly text
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason

> egrep [^(main)] excludes the letter m,a,i,n.

is that [^(main)] matches a single character that is not contained within the brackets, which excludes not only m,a,i,n, but also ( and ). You can find the correct usage of this feature [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions).

Actually, there is already a similar [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) question. It has several forms of negative look-ahead. `^((?!main).)*$` may be one of them satisfying your need.

Answer (score 0):

idk if it's what you want or not but borrowing [@Pushpesh's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55940311/1745001) then with any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '!/(^|[^[:alpha:]])main([^[:alpha:]]|$)/' file
hello 123
hello world
some mainly text
```

or using GNU tools for word boundaries:

```
$ awk '!/\<main\>/' file
hello 123
hello world
some mainly text

$ sed '/\<main\>/d' file
hello 123
hello world
some mainly text
```